# Change string to integer in all lists inside a list using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I got this:

```
X = [['0.4,0,6'],['0.2,0,3'],['0.1,0,8']]
```

And I want to achieve this:

```
X = [[0.4,0,6],[0.2,0,3],[0.1,0,8]]
```

I need to make that change because it's causing me a ValueError:

```
array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0.1,0,8
```

Does anyone have any idea how to make that change?

Comment: `'0.1,0,8'` is a single string, not three float values. Where to you get this data?

Comment: So... What you have is a list of lists whose only content is a string, right? This: `'0.4,0,6'` is **one** string. You should take a look to what split does (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), to split that string by comma and then parse to float **:-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have strings in those sublists, which makes it a little confusing. You'll need to *split* them before converting each item to `float`:

```
>>> [[float(i) for i in lst[0].split(',')] for lst in X]
[[0.4, 0.0, 6.0], [0.2, 0.0, 3.0], [0.1, 0.0, 8.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this to preserve the float/int characteristics of your data:

```
import ast
X = [['0.4,0,6'],['0.2,0,3'],['0.1,0,8']]

print([list(ast.literal_eval(e[0])) for e in X])
```

result:

```
[[0.4, 0, 6], [0.2, 0, 3], [0.1, 0, 8]]
```

each list has only one element, containing a tuple. Using `ast.literal_eval` on the sole element returns a `tuple`, convert to `list` you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `eval()` to convert them from strings to tuples and use `list()` to make the tuples lists:

```
a = [['0.4,0,6'],['0.2,0,3'],['0.1,0,8']]

b = []

for x in a:
    b.append(list(eval(x[0])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

X = [['0.4,0,6'],['0.2,0,3'],['0.1,0,8']]
l = [list(ast.literal_eval(i[0])) for i in X]
```

Output:

```
>>> l
[[0.4, 0, 6], [0.2, 0, 3], [0.1, 0, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid both the brittle parsing of text and the dangerous `eval()`, you can use `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
>>> X = [['0.4,0,6'],['0.2,0,3'],['0.1,0,8']]
>>> import ast
>>> X=[ast.literal_eval(i[0]) for i in X]
>>> X
[(0.4, 0, 6), (0.2, 0, 3), (0.1, 0, 8)]
>>>
```